# Highcharts error csv.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm working on parsing some data from a CSV file, but i get this error :
*Uncaught TypeError: csv.replace is not a function*

I don't know why, can somebody help me ?

This is my `loadCSV.js`:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var parse;
     var csv = Papa.parse("http://1001dev.com/Chahine/wp-content/themes/consulting-child/fonds/DigitalStarsEurope/volatilityFR.csv", {
               download: true,
               complete: function(results) {    
                      console.log(results.data);



                     $("#EuropeVolatilityBtn").click(function() {

                          $('#EuropeVolatility').highcharts({

                              data: {
                                    csv: results
                                    }

                          });

                   });



             }
    });





});
```

You can see the result here in  :
http://1001dev.com/Chahine/fonds/

When you click on the button : Volatilité the message appear.

Thanks a lot,

Cheers,
Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Barbara said, you can use Highcharts data module and parse your data adequately inside `complete` function. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ny0qh8o3/

Answer (score 2):

You've already parsed your CSV file into json using Papa.parse.  Highcharts data is looking for a CSV string, not a json object.

Also, why are you fetching the CSV file outside the click handler?  The CSV will be downloaded even if the user never clicks on that button.

See: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module

```
$.get('data.csv', function(csv) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        data: {
            csv: csv
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        }
    });
});
```